# Selecting appropriate Noda time structures

Tags: nodatime

I have the following data which i was querying with .net time and ran into issues with timezones and spans. I was recommended to use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/).

```
"MarketStates": {
    "dataTimeZone": "America/New_York",
    "monday": [
      {
          "start": "04:00:00",
          "end": "09:30:00",
          "state": "premarket"
      },
      {
          "start": "09:30:00",
          "end": "16:00:00",
          "state": "market"
      }
    ],
        "holidays": [
        "1/1/1998",
        "1/1/1999",
        "1/1/2001"
    ],
    "earlyCloses": {
        "7/3/2000": "13:00:00",
        "7/3/2001": "13:00:00"
    }
}
```

I am writing a function `IsMarketOpen` providing a time to test against, and the above `MarketStates` json database - it returns true if the current time is during market open and false if a holiday or earlyClose.

For the market states (`monday` above) I will use a [`LocalTime`](https://nodatime.org/).

For the `earlyCloses` I plan to use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://nodatime.org/).

For the passed time into this method, I will use a `ZonedDateTime`.

For `holidays` would I need to keep the timezone? I cannot find a *`ZonedDate`*, only [`OffsetDate`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.OffsetDate.html) or [`LocalDate`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.OffsetDate.html)?

In summary, should I keep everything `ZonedDateTime` (since i have the time zone specified in the json database snippet above), or use a `LocalDateTime` and then perform the conversion/testing at that point?

Please bear with me for the above question I didn't realize that time is actually so hard and need guidance for structure selection, I will adapt as per comments if extra context is needed. Thank you.

Comment: "I didn't realize that time is actually so hard" - it takes a while, but it's bearable eventually. Hopefully Noda Time will help make it easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `earlyCloses` looks like it's really a `Dictionary<LocalDate, LocalTime>`, and `holidays` is a `List<LocalDate>`. (As a side note, it's pretty awful that it's not using ISO-8601 for the date format... I can't tell whether those early closes are July 3rd or March 7th.)

The time zone is specified by `dataTimeZone`, but I'd suggest keeping it as a string in the model, and converting it to a `DateTimeZone` when you need to.

The thrust of what I'm saying is that I'd encourage you to make the values in your direct model (loaded from JSON and saved to JSON) match what's actually stored in the JSON. You could have a wrapper around that model which (for example) converted the early closes into `ZonedDateTime` values... but I've generally found it really useful to keep the "plain model" simple, so you can immediately guess the representation in the JSON just from looking at it.